# Trying to scrape data off of dividendinvestor.com

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import some stock data regarding dividend history using Google Sheets.

The data I'm trying to grab is from this page: https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/

(e.g. https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/ibm or https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/msft)

With other sites, I've been able to use a combination of INDEX and IMPORTHTML to get data from a table. For example, if I wanted to get the "`Forward P/E`" for IBM from finviz.com, I do this:

```
=index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=IBM","table", 11),11,10)
```

That grabs table 11 and goes down 11 rows and over 10 columns to get the piece of data that I want.

However, I cannot seem to find any tables to import via IMPORTHTML from the [www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/ibm](http://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/ibm)  site.

I'm trying to import the value to the right of the "Consecutive Dividend Increases" field.

In this case, the output I'm trying to achieve is "19 years".

I've also tried IMPORTXML, but everything I try with `XPATH (using this path: "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[20]" )` fails too.

Any help out there? The desired end result will be that I will dynamically build the dividendinvestor.com URL by appending a different ticker symbol and have a result of how many years of consecutive increases in their dividend payout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice solution proposed by @player0. If you don't want to use `INDEX`, you can go with :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/"&B3,"//a[.='Consecutive Dividend Increases']/following::span[1]")
```

[image: Const]

Update (May 2022) :

New working formula :

[image: New formula]

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN("|";TRUE;IMPORTXML("https://www.dividendinvestor.com/ajax/?action=quote_ajax&symbol="&B2;"//text()"));"\d+ Years")
```

Note : I'm based in Europe, so semi-colons may have to be replaced with commas.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That works! Do you know of any great resources online where I can learn more about this?

Comment: For XPath, https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp is a great place to start. Then, practice.:) To test your expression, use ChroPath addon or online services like https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html or http://xpather.com/

Comment: So, if I wanted to find data from another field on that page, could I simply change out the //a[.='Consecutive Dividend Increases']/ section to have different text?

Comment: Yes. But sometimes you also need to change the element name. For example, to get "Dividend Amount Current" you have to input `//span[.='Dividend Amount Current']/following::span[1]`.

Comment: This now gives N/A, Imported content is empty.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/ibm/", 
 "//span[@class = 'data']"), 9, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That works! Do you know of any great resources online where I can learn more about this?

Comment: no need for any... just right-click the "19 years" ... select "inspect element"... and copy whatever it shows you - https://i.stack.imgur.com/huJof.png

Comment: player0, that hasn't been my experience. When I just copy the "Xpath", I get stuff like this: 
```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/strong
```
And then it just N/A errors